# doWhile loop indentation issue

Tags: typography, algorithms

I have been trying to write multiple loop statements using do-while loops for the flow diagram shown in [1]. However, managing indentation happens to be hard. Can anyone help on this issue?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Do
    \State a,b,c,d,e,m,n
  \doWhile{$!f$} % <--- use \doWhile for the "while" at the end
  
  $g$
  
    \Do
    \State abc
    \doWhile{$!h$}
    
    $i$
    \Do
    \State Pv
    \doWhile{$!j$}
    
    $r s t $
  %  \doWhile{$!$}
  %   \State l
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

The problem is indentation.

Comment: Can you describe what the problem is with the current output? Also please add the documentclass and usepackage statements to the code, especially for algorithms this is very important as there are multiple different ways of setting this up and the solution depends on which way you use.

Comment: Thank you, document class and usepackage  Included. The issue is indentation. The code gives me the same indentation for all lines.

Answer (score 1):

Although white space in program text is typically ignored by programming languages, according to common practice, indentation is used in programs to make them more readable. To achieve this purpose, indentation should generally follow some style in a consistent way, that reflects the program's structure.

In the code that you have, I cannot follow the structure of your program. Unfortunately, the `algorithmicx` package (see [its documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf)) also fails to follow your structure and indents your code in a way that is not what you expect.

In particular, I (and `algorithmicx` also) cannot see:

1. What `$g$` is. If it is some abstract statement, it should be written as `\State $g$` to be indented properly. The same applies to `$i$` and `$r s t$`.
2. Why you expect the lines below `$g$` to be indented not directly below `$g$` but more to the right. This could be explained only if `$g$` denotes some form of block statement (e.g. a `while`) whose body extends to the lines below it.

The result obtained (after adding the missing `\State` macros and some `\medskip` for adding vertical space) reflects the program's structure as `algorithmicx` perceives it:

[image: result 1]

On the other hand, if indeed you want to introduce arbitrary indentation following a block header, you can define a new type of block for this purpose (I named it `\Arbitrary{header} ... \endArbitrary`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%
\algblockdefx[ARBITRARY]{Arbitrary}{endArbitrary}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithmic}
  \Do
    \State a,b,c,d,e,m,n
  \doWhile{$!f$} % <--- use \doWhile for the "while" at the end
  \medskip
  \Arbitrary{$g$}
    \medskip
    \Do
    \State abc
    \doWhile{$!h$}
    \medskip
    \State $i$
    \Do
    \State Pv
    \doWhile{$!j$}
    \medskip
    \State $r s t $
  \endArbitrary
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image: result 2]

Comment: Thank you so much @nickie. 
I am not able to share a screenshot to show what exactly I needed. But your answer is very helpful.

Comment: Hello nickie,  I am able to attach the flow diagram now. That is what I want to implement.  Can you please help now ? Many thanks

Comment: @Hassen, I don't understand. In what form do you want to typeset the algorithm? In pseudocode, like in the beginning of your question, or in a flow diagram, like the one you added now?

Comment: @nikie, as far as I understand, the flow diagram can be implemented, either way,i.e., do-while or while loop. What I want is do-while loop. So, I want the flowchart I posted in a do-while loop.  Thanks

Comment: @Hassen, if you want the flow diagram in form of pseudocode, go ahead and write it in this form. Then, if you need help with typesetting anything specific about it in LaTeX, you can post a question here or edit your existing one.

Comment: Thank you, @nickie,
I leave my pseudocode in the answer section. Please check it when you get some time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the nested Do-While based pseudocode I wrote on LaTex. Someone can check it and can be used for others who might have same problem in the future.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\PassOptionsToPackage{noend}{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %% DoWhile algorithm macro definition 
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\algrule}[1][\algorithmicindent]{\makebox[#1][l]{\hspace*{.5em}\vrule height .75\baselineskip depth .25\baselineskip}}
    
    \newcount\ALG@printindent@tempcnta
    \def\ALG@printindent{%
        \ifnum \theALG@nested>0% is there anything to print
        \ifx\ALG@text\ALG@x@notext% is this an end group without any text?
        % do nothing
        \addvspace{-3pt}% FUDGE for cases where no text is shown, to make the rules line up
        \else
        \unskip
        % draw a rule for each indent level
        \ALG@printindent@tempcnta=1
        \loop
        \algrule[\csname ALG@ind@\the\ALG@printindent@tempcnta\endcsname]%
        \advance \ALG@printindent@tempcnta 1
        \ifnum \ALG@printindent@tempcnta<\numexpr\theALG@nested+1\relax% can't do <=, so add one to RHS and use < instead
        \repeat
        \fi
        \fi
    }
\usepackage{etoolbox}
% the following line injects our new indent handling code in place of the default spacing
\patchcmd{\ALG@doentity}{\noindent\hskip\ALG@tlm}{\ALG@printindent}{}{\errmessage{failed to patch}}
\makeatother
% end vertical rule patch for algorithmicx
\algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\begin{algorithm}%\captionsetup{labelfont={sc,bf}, labelsep=newline}
    \caption{Workspace boundary determination}
    \label{alg:PoEG}    
    \begin{algorithmic}
        \State Input $z_0,~z_f,~n,~m$
        \State \quad \quad ~ $\Delta_z = \dfrac{z_0-z_f}{n}, \textit{tol}$
        \State \quad \quad ~ $\varepsilon_f= 2\pi~, \Delta\varepsilon = \dfrac{\varepsilon_f}{m}$
        \State \quad \quad ~ $k_{\textup{max}}, \Delta\alpha_0, i = j=1$
        \medskip
        \State Output $\boldsymbol{\theta}, \boldsymbol{\psi}, \boldsymbol{z} $
        \medskip
        \State initialize ~$z \gets z_0,~ \psi=\theta =\gets \emptyset$
        \Do
            \Do 
                \Do
                    \Do 
                        \State $\Delta\psi = \psi + \Delta\alpha c\varepsilon$
                        \State $\Delta\theta = \theta + \Delta\alpha s\varepsilon $ 
                        \State $\psi = \psi +\Delta\varepsilon$
                        \State $\theta = \psi + \Delta\varepsilon$ 
                        \State Compute $\boldsymbol{J}_{dh}$ 
                        \State $k = cond(\boldsymbol{J}_{dh})$
        
                    \doWhile{$k<k_{max}$}
        
                    \State $\psi = \psi -\Delta\varepsilon$
                    \State $\theta = \psi - \Delta\varepsilon$ 
        
                    \State $\Delta\alpha = \Delta\alpha/2$
        
                \doWhile{$\Delta\alpha > tol $}
                \State $\psi(i,j) = \psi $
                \State $\theta(i,j) = \theta $
        
                \State $ j =j+1$
                \State $\Delta\alpha = \Delta\alpha_0$
                \State $\varepsilon = \varepsilon + \Delta\varepsilon$
            \doWhile{$\varepsilon < 2\pi$}
        
            \State $ \theta =0$
            \State $\psi =0$
            \State $\varepsilon =0$
            \State $\Delta\alpha=\Delta\alpha_0$
            \State $i=i+1$
            \State $z_i=z+\Delta_z$

        \doWhile{$z<z_f$} \\ % <--- use \doWhile for the "while" at the end
        plot$(\boldsymbol{\psi},\boldsymbol{\theta},\boldsymbol{z})$\\ \medskip Note: $s$ and $c$ stands for sine and cosine, respectively.
        %\endArbitrary
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```